# Grouped Table Issue When Making Cell

Tags: iphone, ios

this is just about to drive me nuts. I'm trying to make a simple grouped table and whenever I run it I get this error:

```
-[__NSCFConstantString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x489c
```

Here's the code that's throwing the line (I put the exact line in asterisks):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *newSpecCell = @"newSpecCell";
NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSString *key = [segmentArray objectAtIndex:section];
NSArray *names = [specsDictionary objectForKey:key];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:newSpecCell];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:newSpecCell];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [names objectAtIndex:row]; // <---
return cell;
```

}

From my logic I'm asking for the `objectAtIndex` from an array but the error says I'm sending it to a constant string.

I've tried a few things (like making a string from `[names objectAtIndex:row]` but it doesn't seem to make any difference. Also, if I use NSLog to show the values in `names` it shows them correctly so I know the array contains the values I need.

Comment: The call to `[specsDictionary objectForKey:key]` is returning an **NSString**, not an **NSArray**. Double check how your `specsDictionary` is being populated.

Comment: Wow, so simple. Thanks a ton, not only does it now work I eliminated two unneeded lines of code.

Comment: @maddy you should put that up as the answer so this question doesn't wind up in the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple problem of array being incorrectly populated. Thanks to Maddy I figured it out quickly enough.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *newSpecCell = @"newSpecCell";
 NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
 // NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
 NSString *key = [segmentArray objectAtIndex:section];
 // NSArray *names = [specsDictionary objectForKey:key];
 NSString *values = [specsDictionary objectForKey:key]; //<--
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:newSpecCell];
 if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                              reuseIdentifier:newSpecCell];
}

cell.textLabel.text = values; //<--
return cell;
}
```

I simply removed the commented rows and modified the cell.textlabel.text as shown and all was well!